# mobile overflow hidden doesn't work in my case

Tags: css, mobile

**In google mobile emulator tool**, click on my demo http://daysof.me/57/promo/promowall%20-%20Copy.html and drag to the right, I have no idea it doesn't get hided out.

[image]

Comment: a picture isnt going to cut it, please post the correct and corresponding code and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Dorvalla I already told you to try my demo in chrome emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use tables for layouts in responsive design??? It's not good idea...

You have some elements wider than width of display. Try to check it and use float/flex for making layouts. Tables are for information, not for layouts